# Creating Dynamic Excel Connection in SSIS

Tags: excel, dynamic, ssis, connection-string

When I use a static ole db > excel connection manager in SSIS I set the file I want to connect to in the excel connection manager, create the data flow excel destination, hook it up to ole db source and map the fields.

In this case I want to do the same but instead of linking to an existing file I want to create a new file and put my data there. Now I know I can do a SQL task and create a new table (sheet effectively) in an existing excel connection but in this case I have made a script task to create the full path where my new file will go e.g. c:\docs\mypjt\fileformarch.xls with this code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolderName As String
    Dim strMonthNameShort As String
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim lastMonth As New Date(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month - 1, 1)
    strFileName = Dts.Variables("FileName").Value.ToString
    strFolderName = Dts.Variables("FolderName").Value.ToString
    strMonthNameShort = MonthName(lastMonth.Month, True)
    strFullPath = strFolderName & strFileName.Substring(0, strFileName.IndexOf(".xls")) & strMonthNameShort & ".xls"

    Dts.Variables("FullPath").Value = strFullPath
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

But I don't understand how to create my dynamic connection and mappings, I tried mucking about with connection strings in my excel connection manager etc to no avial so figure I am not getting the full picture of exactly what I need to do.

Not sure if I need a template with the column headings to set up a default mapping, but then I have read many cases where the excel connection manager only requires an initial connection to "a" file then the dynamic connectionstring proerty takes over when you run it, but then how does it know what the mappings are if you are creating a new file?

I am grateful for any advice you can give.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Have you tried `Dts.Connections("MyExcelConnection").ConnectionString = strFullPath` ? Or in the excel connection manager, you can also use an expression on the ConnectionString property.

Comment: @Dominic Goulet Tried that but to be honest I think I needed something else set up before hand. From the script task I pasted above I then want to:

Comment: 1) create a new file with the path name in the directory 2) in that new file create a new table structure to match the data in SQL table that my SSIS created and 3) Populate the table in the sheet with the data in SQL. I can do 2 and 3 ok but missing the info to do step 1 properly. It seems you have to have an existing connection to an existing workbook to then use a dynamic string. As soon as I set up connection to use dynamic string there's errors.

Comment: In SSIS variable definition for my fullPath and monthname variable  should I have a default value as of just now I don't have any? I ran the package up until the script and the variable FullPath does have the correct string. But now I wonder do I need the full path or just the dynamic file name?